# Synchronize package list

Tags: package

When I look in the `*Packages*` buffer, I see this:

```
polymode           20200411.915  available  melpa      Extensible framework for multiple major modes
```

But, when I search for the same package on MELPA, I see that the available version is `20200606.1106`

I tried `(package-refresh-contents)`, but that doesn't solve the problem. Even worse, the package listed in `*Packages*` buffer was deleted from MELPA, thus installing it is no longer possible.

There doesn't seem to be a straight-forward way to request a particular version of the package either. One or the other would have solved the problem.

Also, deleting the file `archive-contents` in MELPAs archives directory doesn't help, as the file is being re-created with all the same information.

---

This is what my package initialization looks like:

```
(require 'package)

(setf package-archives
      '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))

(package-initialize)
```

Comment: What does your package configuration look like?

Comment: @slondr updated the question with relevant code. Well, if that's what you asked about.

Comment: Very unusual, https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents shows `(polymode . [(20200606 1106)`, hence `M-x package-refresh-contents` can't show another version of polymode. is your archive-contents diff with https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents?

Comment: They are hugely different, running `diff` on them produces 653 lines of output.